# volatile member can not be accessed by member function

Tags: c++, crash, volatile

The following code crashes my program:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class test {
volatile std::vector<std::string> wtf;
public:
    test() {}
    void dope() { wtf.clear(); }
};

int main(){
    (new test())->dope();
    return 0;
}
```

And I have no idea why. When I remove volatile, it works again. So why is volatile a problem ?

Comment: I think the real question is why would you want a `volatile` std::vector?

Comment: I got (with gcc 4.8.1) : `error: passing 'volatile std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >' as 'this' argument of 'void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::clear() [with _Tp = std::basic_string<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::basic_string<char> >]' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]`

Comment: It contains information that has to be accessable by the programm everytime. And it is multithreaded.

Comment: Why the `volatile`?  It makes no sense for an `std::vector` to be `volatile`.

Comment: Volatile doesn't do what you think it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::vector::clear()` doesn't have `volatile` qualifier.

So calling it with a volatile vector is illegal.

BTW, `volatile` is not a magic keyword for multi-threading.
You may use `mutex` to protect access to your vector.